# Selectize vue component closing dropdown after selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, selectize.js

Trying to create a simple selectize vue component but I'm having issue where whenever I select an option and using v-model within the component, the dropdown automatically closes while removing the v-model the dropdown stays open until the specified max items are reached.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <p>With Model: {{ selected }}</p>
  <selectize v-model="selected" :options="options" data-max-items="2"></selectize>

  <p>Without Model: {{ selected }}</p>
  <selectize :options="options" data-max-items="2"></selectize>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('selectize', {
  props: ['options', 'value'],

  template: '<select><slot></slot></select>',

  mounted() {
    $(this.$el).selectize({
      onInitialize: () => {
        this.$el.selectize.setValue(this.value, true)
      },

      onChange: (value) => {
        this.$emit('input', value)
      },

      ...this.mergedSettings,
    })
  },

  computed: {
    mergedSettings() {
      return $.extend({
        options: this.options,
      }, $(this.$el).data())
    },
  },

  watch: {
    value(value) {
      this.$el.selectize.setValue(value, true)
    },
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      { value: 1, text: "One"   },
      { value: 2, text: "Two"   },
      { value: 3, text: "Three" },
      { value: 4, text: "Four"  },
    ],

    selected: [],
  },
})
```

I also created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uk0g69s4/19/

Comment: I worked with vue + selectize a year ago. check if [this repo](https://github.com/lmarqs/odw-form/tree/master/src/components/fields/select) can help you.

Comment: @Imarqs I have checked the repo but cannot figure out how you setValue. How do you setValue of selectize to not close the dropdown?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, on the [component creation](https://github.com/lmarqs/odw-form/blob/075cb6864bcdd8a17d56a66c1b7e8df5b9b32f09/src/components/fields/select/make.js#L10) you can pass the [option](https://github.com/lmarqs/odw-form/blob/075cb6864bcdd8a17d56a66c1b7e8df5b9b32f09/src/components/fields/select/options.js#L4) `closeAfterSelect: false`.

Comment: @Imarqs I'm using selectize v0.12.6 and `closeAfterSelect` option is `false` by default https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/v0.12.6/dist/js/selectize.js#L2711

Comment: I see. Now I remember how I solved it. I will put it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not proud of this solution but it is the better thing I could figure out.

Create a `SELF_CHANGED` attribute to check if the change was triggered internally or externally...

```js
Vue.component('selectize', {
  props: ['options', 'value'],
  data() {
    return {
      SELF_CHANGED: false
    }
  },
  template: `
    <select>
        <slot></slot>
    </select>
  `,
  mounted() {
    $(this.$el).selectize({
      onInitialize: () => {
        this.$el.selectize.setValue(this.value, true)
      },

      onChange: (value) => {
        this.SELF_CHANGED = true
        this.$emit('input', value)
      },

      ...this.mergedSettings,
    })
  },

  computed: {
    mergedSettings() {
      return $.extend({
        options: this.options,
      }, $(this.$el).data())
    },
  },

  watch: {
    value(value) {
      if (!this.SELF_CHANGED) {
        this.$el.selectize.setValue(value, true)
      }
      this.SELF_CHANGED = false
    },
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [{
        value: 1,
        text: "One"
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        text: "Two"
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        text: "Three"
      },
      {
        value: 4,
        text: "Four"
      },
    ],
    selected: [],
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sifter/0.5.3/sifter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microplugin/0.0.3/microplugin.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>With Model: {{ selected }}</p>
  <selectize v-model="selected" :options="options" data-max-items="2"></selectize>
  <p>Without Model: {{ selected }}</p>
  <selectize :options="options" data-max-items="2"></selectize>
</div>
```